# How to set an aliases in bashrc to concatenate arguments

Tags: bash, aliases

I want to set an alias in bashrc to preform an ssh command

```
alias sshh='ssh 192.168.1."$1"'
```

then I can use

```
$> sshh 306
```

to perform

```
$> ssh 192.168.1.306
```

It seems I didn't get the command right.

Comment: It behaves differently to put the argument in beginning a string or in the end of the string.  See the reference does not help me. I still do not know what is wrong with my alias command.

Comment: I do not want to use function. Is it possible to do that?  If you know how,  could you please simply fix the alias command to make it work?  Thanks!